# cómo hago input dinámico?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo una pequeña página y necesito ayuda con un detalle para el `update` de esta tabla, el actualizar los datos si funciona.

Explico como es que cargo los `select`, el primero corresponde al equipo (todo está en la base de datos), el segundo `select` se carga con `Ajax` según la primera selección (corresponde a los insumos de ese equipo) y ahora quiero saber cómo podría hacer que, según la selección de el insumo, cargar el stock actual en el `input number` para actualizarlo más fácilmente sin tener que ver la tabla con los datos previamente.

[image: Así está la sección actualmente]

Código HTML:

```html
<select name='eq' id='eq'>
 <option value="0">Seleccione Equipo</option>
 <?php
    $sq = "select * from EQUIPO";
    $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sq);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<option value=".$row['ID_EQUIPO'].">".$row['NOM_EQUIPO']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name='ins' id='ins'>
<option value="0"> Seleccione INSUMO</option>
</select>


<input required type="number" min="0" name="st" id="st" placeholder="Nuevo Stock">
<input type="submit" name="Actualizar" value="Actualizar Datos">
```

Así es el Ajax que tengo:

```js
<script language="javascript"">
$(document).on('change','#eq', function(){
    var id=$(this).val();//obtengo el valor seleccionado
    $.ajax({  
        url : 'getINSUMO.php',   
        data : { id : id },
        type : 'GET',
        //dataType : 'json',//si se requiere obtener un json
        success : function(res) {
          $("#ins").html(res);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Y este es el php que hace la consulta para el segundo select:

```html
<?php
require("bd.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "error";
    exit();
}
 
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die("No se encuentra");


   $id=$_GET["id"];//si se requiere el id enviado para su consulta
    $sq = "select * from INSUMO where ID_EQUIPO = $id";
    $res= mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
    $result="";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $result.="<option value=".$row['ID_INSUMO'].">".$row['NOMBRE_INSUMO']."</option>";

    }
 echo "<option value=0> Seleccione INSUMO</option>";
 echo utf8_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: También con `ajax` lo puedes recuperar para mostrarlo. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Listo ya puse el código

Comment: Puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo para el segundo `select`, cuando cambie, haces una consulta con `ajax` para recuperar el valor del stock. Sólo debes cambiar ciertos detalles al código que ya tienes 
, como los `id`, por ejemplo: `$(document).on('change','#ins', function(){`. Estoy seguro que lo vas a lograr!